# db_fetch_object returning null

Tags: 6, database

This is the line:

```
$row = db_fetch_object($result);
```

While $result is valid but $row is getting a null value which I've checked with is_null.

As per this function's @return value, it can only return FALSE in failure.

Also mysql_db_object states the same.

What could be the reason it is returning null?

Comment: FALSE !== NULL ...

Comment: What is the actual query?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [`db_fetch_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.mysql.inc/function/db_fetch_object/6.x) could also return `NULL`, contrary to what the documentation says. The documentation assumes you aren't passing to the function a value that for PHP is equivalent to `FALSE`, for example `NULL`, an empty array, or an uninitialized variable. If the function gets a value that for PHP is equivalent to `FALSE`, the function will not execute any instruction, and it will return `NULL`.

```php
function db_fetch_object($result) {
  if ($result) {
    return mysql_fetch_object($result);
  }
}
```

The same is true for other database engines, for example [PostgreSQL](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.pgsql.inc/function/db_fetch_object/6.x), which uses the following function.

```php
function db_fetch_object($result) {
  if ($result) {
    return pg_fetch_object($result);
  }
}
```

This is usually not a problem, since the function should normally be called as in the following snippets.

```php
 if ($category = db_fetch_object(db_query('SELECT cid, title, block FROM {aggregator_category} WHERE cid = %d', $id))) {
    $block['subject'] = check_plain($category->title);
    $result = db_query_range('SELECT i.* FROM {aggregator_category_item} ci LEFT JOIN {aggregator_item} i ON ci.iid = i.iid WHERE ci.cid = %d ORDER BY i.timestamp DESC, i.iid DESC', $category->cid, 0, $category->block);
    $read_more = theme('more_link', url('aggregator/categories/' . $category->cid), t("View this category's recent news."));
  }
```

```php
  while ($item = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $items[] = theme('aggregator_block_item', $item);
  }
```

In both the cases, the control statements will not be executed, since for them `NULL` is equivalent to `FALSE`.